# Cannot access or download external resources from inside pod (connection refused)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm on a `minikube` single node environment (with default settings):

```
|----------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|
| Profile  | VM Driver | Runtime |      IP      | Port | Version | Status  | Nodes |
|----------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|
| minikube | docker    | docker  | 192.168.49.2 | 8443 | v1.22.3 | Running |     1 |
|----------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|
```

I need to clone some external repositories (hosted publicly on https://bitbucket.org) from inside a Pod. From what I've seen there must be some issues with the network policies.

For instance, this is the output from inside a generic pod inside the `default` namespace:

```
root@netbox-85cdcc9587-hlxjb:/# git clone https://bitbucket.org/<project_name>/<repo_name>/
Cloning into '<repo_name>'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/<project_name>/<repo_name>/': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Connection refused
```

I've already read about it at the following resources but I couldn't find anything useful:

- https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/network_policy/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

What I've already tried:

1. Restarting the minikube cluster with Calico CNI (`minikube start --cni calico`)
2. Creating a network policy that allows all egress just for testing

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-all-egress
spec:          
  podSelector: {}
  egress:           
  - {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

Am I missing some trivial steps or is there some issues in the cluster I can investigate more to verify?

Comment: check `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and check for the DNS setting "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]

Comment: Where shall I check this? Directly inside my local environment or inside the minikube environment? Because in both cases that file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by using a custom nameserver as @HarshManvar suggested but since I'm on minikube I needed to find a way to deploy it on cluster level.
Looking at the docs (https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/filesync/) I found this that interestingly has in the example section exactly what I was looking for.

So basically just do the following:

```
mkdir -p ~/.minikube/files/etc
echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > ~/.minikube/files/etc/resolv.conf
minikube stop
minikube start
```

And the nameserver should be correctly deployed. I verified that the connection outside the cluster local network worked as expected, without the need of chaning CNI or using egress network policies.

Comment: `echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > ~/.minikube/files/etc/resolv.conf` - doing this way can you still resolve the name `nslookup kubernetes.default` when you exec into a pod?

Comment: @gohm'c yes I do actually. `Name: kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` I suppose Kidnet CNI still works as expected.